# Translate my magento custom module in frontend

Tags: magento

I have done a magento custom module and I want to make a translation for it.

How can I do that, without creating another translation module ?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use built in translation methods and define all your strings in templates like this:

```
<?php echo $this->__('yourtext'); ?>
```

if you need to use strings in classes or blocks you can get the context from helper class like this:

```
<?php echo Mage::helper('yourextension')->__('yourtext');?>
```

and if you need to define your own translation file then use this in your etc/config.xml

```
<config>
    <frontend>
        <translate>
            <modules>
                <Your_Extension>
                    <files>
                        <default>Your_Extension.csv</default>
                    </files>
                </Your_Extension>
            </modules>
        </translate>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

Comment: the first `$this->__('youtext')` method will work for blocks as well. And for controllers. Only models need the second way.

Comment: the place to put your translation is `app/locale/language_CODE/Your_Extension.csv`

Comment: it is locale_CODE not language_CODE