# How to add a custom translation file for Magento 1.9

Tags: magento, translate

I need to add a customised translation for a website in Magento 1.9.3.7.

I am using translate.csv file, for example:

```
"Why not","Pourquoi pas"
```

I have added the file to this location:

```
 app/design/frontend/[my theme]/default/locale/fr_FR/translate.csv
```

But it does not look as it is being picked up and used.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You can add your custom translations by creating a module:

https://inchoo.net/magento/how-to-add-your-own-translations-to-custom-modules/

or you can check:

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/167072/how-to-add-custom-translations/178701

Answer (score 0):

You can also check:

https://belvg.com/blog/magento-1-9-basic-ways-to-provide-a-translation.html

[Translate my magento custom module in frontend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5661355/translate-my-magento-custom-module-in-frontend)

http://www.webspeaks.in/2013/06/how-to-add-translation-to-custom-module-in-magento.html

https://inchoo.net/magento/how-to-add-your-own-translations-to-custom-modules/